# Get wordpress post id from a given url

Tags: php, wordpress

I was wondering how I can get the post ID from a wordpress post when I provide a given URL.

For example I want to get the post ID from the url http://stormable.com/heroes/illidan/
I'm not looking for the url of the post that I'm on but of the url I'm providing.

```
$postid = post id from the url http://stormable.com/heroes/illidan/
```

I'm not sure if this is possible but this is what I'm looking for so I can then use the post id.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php $postid = url_to_postid( $url ); ?>
```

This function  requires Rewrite Rules to be enabled.
though link provided by you already rewrited.

Answer (score 0):

Check out url_to_post_id: [url_to_postid](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid)
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid